# Image Optimization Needs

Tags: image, optimization, web, load, monitoring

I tested my website load performance using tools like [100pulse.com](http://100pulse.com) that show my website took unusual time to load because of improper image optimization. Can anyone suggest good image optimization technique to improve my website response time?

Answer (score 2):

**Image Optimization**

Image compression is either lossy or lossless: Lossy works by discarding information from the original file, and lossless retains all the original data (though, the file size tends to be bigger).

By selectively decreasing the number of colors in the image, fewer bytes are required to store the data. The effect is nearly invisible but it makes a very large difference in file size! **Therefore this results in quicker page download times**

There's a variety of image compression algorithms that take different approaches to reducing file size, and the tools listed below utilize a number of those to minimize the size of your images.

**TinyPNG** (https://tinypng.com/)

TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file size of your PNG files.

OR

**TinyJPG** (https://tinyjpg.com/) 
For JPG Files

**Reference:** http://websitespeedoptimizations.com/ImageOptzPost.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use this ***Smushit*** to optimize your images, they drop down their size without damaging the quality.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/

They give you a longer explanation about why it is cool, it really helped me while working on some mobile games and flash apps.

Comment: have you found what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the image some bash love.

"sips -s formatOptions 60 image/path"
for image/path, you can also just drag the image in.

you can also try to resize the image to save speed

"sips -Z 800 image/path"

this code will keep the aspect ration

for a nontech solution
TinyPNG (https://tinypng.com/)

advanced users try out (guetzli) it can take several minutes to optimize one image but its really good.